# Centering a javascript image inside a span in Bootstrap 3

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am having an problem where I have to center two security seals at the bottom of a responsive payment form, and one of them works fine but the other, that contains a  tag, does not

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row text-center">
    <div class="footer">
      <div class="col-md-12  col-sm-12" >
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://sealserver.trustwave.com/seal.js?code=<?= $this->model->getTWKey() ?>"></script>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12" >
        <span id="cdSiteSeal2" >          
          <script type="text/javascript" src="//tracedseals.starfieldtech.com/siteseal/get?scriptId=cdSiteSeal2&amp;cdSealType=Seal2&amp;sealId=55e4ye7y7mb73952743bf753a95b7cfvma3y7mb7355e4ye734fda9346a2ed18a"></script>
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can see the page [here](http://sageccpayment.com/?id=9).  I've tried several different things (ie offsets and creating a centering class ala)

```
.img-center {margin:0 auto;}
```

But nothing has worked.

Since the first javascript widget centers fine, I can only conclude that the  is doing something to prevent it from working.

I am pretty sure I am not doing this the totally correct way, but I am a backend developer not a UI  designer and I'm just trying to get something to my client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By inspecting the element that the javascript inserts, you can see it's a `div` that needs centering, not an image.

Try adding this CSS rule:

```
#siteSealFauxBadge > div { 
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: thank you...it works...btw i was trying to inspect it but i just couldn't get my head around this one, and i learned something new!

Comment: As you say you're a back end developer so understandable. Might be worth getting familiar with the inspector, it has SO many useful features these days.

Answer (score 0):

add css

```
#siteSealFauxBadge div:first-child {
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

You will get the result as shown in picture
[image]